# Python Last 6 Results, removing the last

Tags: python, for-loop

I just can't get it done. Therefore I'll post the full code.

The .csv used is from http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/E0.csv

Now when run, the variables home_team_a, home_team_d, away_team_a and away_team_d are based on all of the previous matches but I want them to be based always on the last 6 matches.

```
import csv, math, ast, numpy as np

def poisson(actual, mean):
    return math.pow(mean, actual) * math.exp(-mean) / math.factorial(actual)

csvFile = '20152016.csv'

team_list = []

k = open('team_list.txt', 'w')
k.write("""{
""")

csvRead = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
next(csvRead)

for row in csvRead:
    if row[2] not in team_list:
        team_list.append(row[2])
    if row[3] not in team_list:
        team_list.append(row[3])

team_list.sort()

for team in team_list:
    k.write(""" '%s': {'home_goals': 0, 'away_goals': 0, 'home_conceded': 0, 'away_conceded': 0, 'home_games': 0, 'away_games': 0, 'alpha_h': 0, 'beta_h': 0, 'alpha_a': 0, 'beta_a': 0},
""" % (team))

k.write("}")
k.close()

s = open('team_list.txt', 'r').read()
dict = ast.literal_eval(s)

GAMES_PLAYED = 0
WEEKS_WAIT = 4
TOTAL_VALUE = 0

csvRead = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
next(csvRead)

for game in csvRead:
    home_team = game[2]
    away_team = game[3]

    home_goals = int(game[4])
    away_goals = int(game[5])

    home_win_prob = 0
    draw_win_prob = 0
    away_win_prob = 0

    curr_home_goals = 0
    curr_away_goals = 0
    avg_home_goals = 1
    avg_away_goals = 1

    team_bet = ''
    ev_bet = ''

    # GETTING UPDATED VARIABLES
    for key, value in dict.items():
        curr_home_goals += dict[key]['home_goals']
        curr_away_goals += dict[key]['away_goals']

        if GAMES_PLAYED > (WEEKS_WAIT * 10):
            avg_home_goals = curr_home_goals / (GAMES_PLAYED)
            avg_away_goals = curr_away_goals / (GAMES_PLAYED)


    # CALCULATING FACTORS
    if GAMES_PLAYED > (WEEKS_WAIT * 10):
        home_team_a = (dict[home_team]['alpha_h'] + dict[home_team]['alpha_a']) / 2
        away_team_a = (dict[away_team]['alpha_h'] + dict[away_team]['alpha_a']) / 2

        home_team_d = (dict[home_team]['beta_h'] + dict[home_team]['beta_a']) / 2
        away_team_d = (dict[away_team]['beta_h'] + dict[away_team]['beta_a']) / 2

        home_team_exp = avg_home_goals * home_team_a * away_team_d
        away_team_exp = avg_away_goals * away_team_a * home_team_d


    # RUNNING POISSON   
        l = open('poisson.txt', 'w')

        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                prob = poisson(i, home_team_exp) * poisson(j, away_team_exp)
                l.write("Prob%s%s = %s\n" % (i, j, prob))

        l.close()

        with open('poisson.txt') as f:
            for line in f:

                home_goals_m = int(line.split(' = ')[0][4])
                away_goals_m = int(line.split(' = ')[0][5])

                prob = float(line.split(' = ')[1])

                if home_goals_m > away_goals_m:
                    home_win_prob += prob
                elif home_goals_m == away_goals_m:
                    draw_win_prob += prob
                elif home_goals_m < away_goals_m:
                    away_win_prob += prob

    #CALCULATE VALUE
        bet365odds_h, bet365odds_d, bet365odds_a = float(game[23]), float(game[24]), float(game[25])

        ev_h = (home_win_prob * (bet365odds_h - 1)) - (1 - home_win_prob)
        ev_d = (draw_win_prob * (bet365odds_d - 1)) - (1 - draw_win_prob)
        ev_a = (away_win_prob * (bet365odds_a - 1)) - (1 - away_win_prob)

        highestEV = max(ev_h, ev_d, ev_a)

        if (ev_h == highestEV) and (ev_h > 0):
            team_bet = home_team
            ev_bet = ev_h
            if home_goals > away_goals:
                TOTAL_VALUE += (bet365odds_h - 1)
            else:
                TOTAL_VALUE -= 1

        elif (ev_d == highestEV) and (ev_d > 0):
            team_bet = 'Draw'
            ev_bet = ev_d
            if home_goals == away_goals:
                TOTAL_VALUE += (bet365odds_d - 1)
            else:
                TOTAL_VALUE -= 1
        elif (ev_a == highestEV) and (ev_a > 0):
            team_bet = away_team
            ev_bet = ev_a
            if home_goals < away_goals:
                TOTAL_VALUE += (bet365odds_a - 1)
            else:
                TOTAL_VALUE -= 1

        if (team_bet != '') and (ev_bet != ''):
            print ("Bet on '%s' (EV = %s)" % (team_bet, ev_bet))    
            print (TOTAL_VALUE)

    # UPDATE VARIABLES AFTER MATCH HAS BEEN PLAYED
    dict[home_team]['home_goals'] += home_goals
    dict[home_team]['home_conceded'] += away_goals
    dict[home_team]['home_games'] += 1

    dict[away_team]['away_goals'] += away_goals
    dict[away_team]['away_conceded'] += home_goals
    dict[away_team]['away_games'] += 1

    GAMES_PLAYED += 1

    # CREATE FACTORS
    if GAMES_PLAYED > (WEEKS_WAIT * 10):
        for key, value in dict.items():
            alpha_h = (dict[key]['home_goals'] / dict[key]['home_games']) / avg_home_goals
            beta_h = (dict[key]['home_conceded'] / dict[key]['home_games']) / avg_away_goals

            alpha_a = (dict[key]['away_goals'] / dict[key]['away_games']) / avg_away_goals
            beta_a = (dict[key]['away_conceded'] / dict[key]['away_games']) / avg_home_goals

            dict[key]['alpha_h'] = alpha_h
            dict[key]['beta_h'] = beta_h
            dict[key]['alpha_a'] = alpha_a
            dict[key]['beta_a'] = beta_a
```

Comment: Does this code run at all? It's basically doing `if [a, b, c] > 50`, which seems unlikely to work.

Comment: The `if (records > 50)` line is sketchy. I dont think its valid since `records` is a list object from iterating over a `csv.Reader` object. So you are saying `if list > 50` which wont work.

Comment: Please see updated post

Answer (score 4):

Use a deque to keep the 6 most recent items in memory; adding a new record will "push out" the oldest one.

```
import collections
import itertools
import csv

with open("foo.csv") as fh:
    # Skip the first 44 rows
    csv_read = islice(csv.reader(fh), 44, None)

    # Initialize the deque with the next 6 rows
    d = collections.deque(islice(csv_read, 6), 6)

    for record in csv_read:
        d.append(record)
        print(list(d))  # Rows 46-51, then 47-52, then 48-53, etc
```

Because you set the maximum length of the deque to 6, each append to a "full" deque pushes out the older one. On the first iteration, `d.append` pushes out row 45 and adds row 51. On the next iteration, adding row 52 pushes out row 46, etc.

---

In general, a deque is a data structure that is like a combination of a queue and a stack; you can add or remove items to either end efficiently, but accessing an arbitrary item or modifying the "middle" is slow. Here, we're taking advantage of the fact that appending to a full deque causes an implicit removal from the opposite end.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if seen_records == 200:
    recs = list(csvRead)[seen_records - 6:seen_records + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this....

```
previous_index = 0
previous_max = 6 # max number of previous numbers to remember
previous = [None for _ in range(previous_max)]
csvFile = 'X.csv'
seen_records = 0
csvRead = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
# Enumerate over the records to keep track of the index of each one
for i, records in enumerate(csvRead):
    if (i > 50):
        seen_records =+ 1
        if previous_index == previous_max:
            previous_index = 0 # Reset to the beginning when we reach the end
        # Store the record and increment the index to the next location
        previous[previous_index] = record
        previous_index += 1
```

This creates a very basic array of length `previous_max` and just stores the oldest data at index 0 and newest at `previous_max -1`.